# Laravel where on relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have a M-M relationship on `User` and `Roles`. Also, one `User` belongs to `Clinic`. I would like to filter out all users belonging to one role, which have specific `clinic_id`. I am trying with this one but it doesn't work:

```
$user = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first()
                 ->users->where('clinic_id', Auth::user()->clinic_id)->get();
```

I am getting an error on this one

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in
```

Relationship is defined fine, and if I exclued the `with()` I get back all users who are admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `roles` based on your role relationship name.

```
$clinic_id = auth()->user()->clinic_id;

$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'admin');
})->where('clinic_id', $clinic_id)->get();
```